# domDocument encoding not match with database

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm using domDocument to find html tags.

```
 $mensaje = "Te informamos que la parada <b>Plaza de la Estación</b> está
   próxima a vaciarse, el día <b>2013-04-22</b> a las <b>17:34:50</b>.";

$dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf8_general_ci');
          // load the html into the object ***/
          $dom->loadHTML($mensaje);

          //discard white space
          $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
          $nodeList= $dom->getElementsByTagName('b'); // here u use your desired tag

          $items = array();
          for($i=0; $i < $nodeList->length; $i++) {
                    $node = $nodeList->item($i);
                    $items[] = trim($node->nodeValue);
          }
          var_dump($items);
```

$mensaje is extracted from my database, this field is utf8_general_ci, but it fails:

```
array(3) { 
 [0]=> string(21) "Plaza de la EstaciÃ³n" 
  [1]=> string(10) "2013-04-22" 
  [2]=> string(8) "17:34:50" }
```

The first element has bad encoding.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Add a meta tag to set content-type.

Answer (score 1):

The enconding you've specified when creating the `DOMDocument` object isn't valid for XML documents. `utf8_general_ci` is a MySQL enconding. Replace it by `UTF-8`.
Also make sure that the encoding of your php file is set to UTF-8.

Comment: Although you're correct about the wrong character set, passing it to the constructor won't make a difference here because you're loading an HTML document.